# Intellij IDEA ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 and am getting a "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" message.  Now I have been doing searches for over an hour and have read many posts where people have been advised to run the jquery script first.  I have done this and the page loads fine in the browser window.  Everything works there.  This is an issue with Intellij IDEA.  I downloaded the JQUERY and JQUERY UI libraries and am linking to them with an absolute path on my hard drive.  I have tried linking to the online ones as well.  I'm not sure how to search for what I need because there are so many false positives, so that is why I'm posting.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" lightbox.js
c:\Users\Aaron\IdeaProjects\DataStructures\Treehouse\src\js\lightbox.js:4
var $overlay = $(''); //creates jquery obj,
               ^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object. (c:\Users\Aaron\IdeaProjects\DataStructures\Treehouse\src\js\lightbox.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Process finished with exit code 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Image Gallery</h1>
<ul id="imageGallery">
    <li><a href="images/refferal_machine.png"><img src="images/refferal_machine.png" width="100" alt="Refferal Machine By Matthew Spiel"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/space-juice.png"><img src="images/space-juice.png" width="100" alt="Space Juice by Mat Helme"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/education.png"><img src="images/education.png" width="100" alt="Education by Chris Michel"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png"><img src="images/copy_mcrepeatsalot.png" width="100" alt="Wanted: Copy McRepeatsalot by Chris Michel"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/sebastian.png"><img src="images/sebastian.png" width="100" alt="Sebastian by Mat Helme"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/skill-polish.png"><img src="images/skill-polish.png" width="100" alt="Skill Polish by Chris Michel"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/chuck.png"><img src="images/chuck.png" width="100" alt="Chuck by Mat Helme"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/library.png"><img src="images/library.png" width="100" alt="Library by Tyson Rosage"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/boat.png"><img src="images/boat.png" width="100" alt="Boat by Griffin Moore"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/illustrator_foundations.png"><img src="images/illustrator_foundations.png" width="100" alt="Illustrator Foundations by Matthew Spiel"></a></li>
    <li><a href="images/treehouse_shop.jpg"><img src="images/treehouse_shop.jpg" width="100" alt="Treehouse Shop by Eric Smith"></a></li>
</ul>
<script src="C:\Users\Aaron\.IntelliJIdea14\system\extLibs\http_code.jquery.com_jquery-2.0.0.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Aaron\.IntelliJIdea14\system\extLibs\http_ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_jqueryui_1.10.2_jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

AND HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"><div></div></div>'); //creates jquery obj, $ is naming convention
var $image = $("<img>");
var $caption = $("<p></p>");
var $index= 0; //Will keep track of image endex from prev/next
var $galleryLength = $("#imageGallery li").length; //store total number of images

//Setup overlay
$overlay.children("div").append($image);//Adds image to the overlay jquery object
$overlay.children("div").append($caption); //Adds caption to the overlay, AFTER the image.
$overlay.children("div").append("<button id='btnPrev'><h4> < </h4></button>"); //create prev button
$overlay.children("div").append("<button id='btnNext'><h4> > </h4></button>"); //create next button
$("body").append($overlay); //adds tag to end of <body>, css for overlay contained in <div>

//updates the image
var updateImage = function(imageLoc, captionText){
    $image.attr("src", imageLoc); //sets $image object to loc of img so its added to overlay
    $caption.text(captionText); //Adds alt attribute text to caption so its displayed below img
};

//captures the click event, when an image is clicked
$("#imageGallery a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents browser frop opening img in new window
    var imageLoc = $(this).attr("href"); //stores attribute in var. ex: "images/space-juice.png"
    var captionText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt"); //Store text from alt attr of img's

    $index = $(this).parent().index(); //update index to current selected image
    console.log($index);
    updateImage(imageLoc, captionText); //Passes loc and caption info to update image
    $overlay.slideDown(imageLoc); //display overlay when img clicked
});

//Button Click Events
$("#btnNext").click(function(event){
    button(true);
});

$("#btnPrev").click(function(event){
    button(false);
});

var button = function(next){

    if(next == true){ //if next is true move forward an image
        $index++;
    }
    else{ //otherwise go to previous image
        $index--;
    }

    //If index is out of bounds reset to first image or last image as needed
    if($index < 0){
        $index = $galleryLength - 1;
    }
    else if($index > $galleryLength - 1){
        $index = 0;
    }

    //selects the element by index and then gets the link to the image
    var newImage = $("#imageGallery li").get($index).getElementsByTagName("a");
    //Store link information in variables
    var imageLoc = $(newImage).attr("href");
    var captionText = $(newImage).children("img").attr("alt");
    //Update the current image with new image information
    updateImage(imageLoc, captionText);

};

//captures the click event, when the overlay is clicked
$overlay.click(function(event){
    if(event.target.id == "overlay"){
        $(this).slideUp("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: should be using web paths not hard drive file paths for your scripts

Comment: I was using a web path before, I only changed it to hard drive to see if I could somehow get it to work in intellij IDEA.

Comment: did you wrap code in `document.ready`?

Comment: That doesn't work because it starts with a $ and triggers the error.

$(document).ready(function() {
^
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: your paths are not right or you are loading this code before jQuery loads

Comment: Look in network tab of browser dev tools

Comment: When I open the HTML file in the web browser all of my jQuery loads and works fine.  It is only when I run the .js file in Intellij IDEA that I get the error.

Comment: config setting then in Intellij for library resources probably needs setting. I don't know that IDE

Comment: Yeah I'm hoping that an Intellij Idea expert will see this and know what setting it is.

Comment: I use php storm...jetbrains docs should have the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this for jquery and any other framework (tested in idea ultimate 2019.2)

1. Go to File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries
2. Click Download...
3. Select jQuery (you can type "jquery" to quickly find it)
4. Download and install

Normally, IDEA should now recognize jquery and provide documentation. You can verify this in the inspection popup at the bottom of the IDEA (the policeman icon)

[image]